# Create weekly calendar of git commits

Tags: git, bash

I'm trying to output a "calendar" view of my git commits for the week. (Can you tell it's timelog Friday?). All I want to see is my commits, on all branches, their times, commit title, short hash. So far I have a loop that loops through the last five days and does this:

```
echo ----
echo $(git log --after="$currentdate 00:00" --before="$currentdate 23:59" --author="$USR" --branches --pretty=format:"commit: %h | date: %ad | title: %s %n")
```

The output the loop looks something like:

```
------
commit: <hashnum> | date: Mon | title: Contain height of logo with parent and max-height commit: <hashnum> |  date: Mon  | title: Change how the transform happens
------
commit: <hashnum> | date: Tue | title: remove transform and tweak span placement in hamburger
------
etc.
```

I'm not sure how best to proceed. My first thought is to save each echoed string into an array, then parse them by some delimiter I put in the format, but that seems more complicated than it needs to be. I've also tried without a loop just piping the `git log` through `column`, but that doesn't look like it will work.

Am I on the right track, or is there a simpler way?

Here is an example of what I'd like to output:

```
        Mon             |           Tue            |      Wed   |    
<hash> 8:00 did a thing |   <hash> 12:15 did anothe|   <hash>   |  
<hash> 9:15 hamburg menu|   <hash> 2:30 asdf       |      etc   |
```

Answer (score 1):

The output won't look the same, but you could try:

`git log --since=7.days --author="$(git config user.name)"`

This will output something similar to this:

```
commit [hash]
Author: [user] <[email]>
Date:   Sun Dec 4 19:03:55 2016 -0800

    Did some things

commit [hash]
Author: [user] <[email]>
Date:   Fri Dec 2 18:35:33 2016 -0800

    Fixed a thing
(END)
```

Assuming you only made 2 commits in the past 7 days

Comment: Oops I answered before seeing your edit. I'll leave this here but I see that it is not what you wanted.